# Best H.264 settings in Handbrake for lowest CPU drain

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

Actual file size is NOT an issue since I am deploying a standalone application or kiosk. But CPU drain is an issue. What are the optimum H.264 export settings to use in handbrake in this scenario?

Comment: Asking for a 'best setting' for anything is off-topic on Super User as such questions generate opinionated and biased answers.

Comment: Stick with baseline profile stuff, don't select any of the higher h.264 levels or high profile stuff, CABAC entropy encoding can be a heavy drain on decoding. Basically don't enable any fancy features and go with a high-ish bandwidth. Start with the "Normal" profile and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong.

Codec settings don't affect CPU load at all. No matter what settings you use, it will use entire computational power available to finish as soon as possible. Because unused resources are wasted resources - if you're going to use, say, only 50% of your CPU's power, you could just as well use half as powerful CPU.

I guess you're having a problem with other programs being unresponsive while encoding is in progress. The standard solution to this problem is juggling with priority settings. In Windows, you should have a look at [scheduling priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx). You can try them by right-clicking a process in Task Manager and choosing something from the *Set priority* menu (just don't use *Realtime*, it can block a system completely). Set higher priority for your main app and lower one for background process. (This can be done programmatically too.)

In Linux [process niceness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)) plays a similar role. The lower niceness a process has, the more CPU time it is assigned. You can set higher niceness (ie. lower priority) from any user's context. Lowering niceness can be done only by root.

Or if you're using Linux and you just want to set a hard limit on CPU usage, [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) may be the right solution for you. I'm not aware of any similar mechanisms in Windows.

Comment: I'd assume that OP is wishing to limit the computational power required for h.264 *decoding*. There are many quality settings that can be enabled to reduce bandwidth required at the cost of increased CPU load on the decoder side and not all systems have a GPU capable of fully offloading the decoding task from the CPU. Also not all GPUs are capable of decoding some of the higher feature levels of h.264 so a "most compatible" level might be preferable. An older CPU or a low powered ARM core may not be able to decode h.264 high profile without assistance.